# SharePoint Online 2013 Designer Workflow stuck on Starting

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, designer-workflow

Hi I have a Designer workflow that runs when an item is created or edited. All of a sudden, the workflow gets stuck at starting. If I terminate the workflow and start it again manually, it runs fine and gets completed. Why does this happen?

Comment: Is the user creating / editing as system account ? Then workflow won't run